# Make rollover image pop up and to left

Tags: javascript, position, rollover

I have a simple rollover script I want to use to make a profile thumb get bigger so you can actually see the person's face. 

`Problem is when the image expands it is throwing off page layout`.  Is there a way to make the image right hand corner stay the same but expand up and to the left covering old image and anything else it needs to cover?

Thanks for suggestions.

```
<tr>
<td>Joe Smith</td>
<td>
<a href="detail.html" onmouseover="document.pic.src='images/smallpic.gif'" onmouseout="document.pic.src='images/bigpic.gif'">
<img src="images/bigpic.gif" width="147" height="82" border="0" name="pic" alt="pic" />
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

next person...

Comment: Would you provide us with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wcfA4/  I didn't use real images but it gives you the idea.  Here image goes down and to the right.  I want it to go up and to the left.

Comment: Sorry but the image isn't expanding. Please check your fiddle again and if possible use some example images.

Answer (score 0):

you also have to set the `position , height & width` for the image on mouseover and mouseout.
also
 you can use `thumbPopup` utility in jquery,example here..[link](http://home.comcast.net/~littlemoe85/thumbhover/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle you cant go up and to the left because there is no space to go there.

Here is some code that uses fixed values instead of calculating them, if you want it to be complicated using thumbs then you should pre load a loading image, when the mouse goes over load the big image/show the loading and when the big image is loaded set the src of the original image and redo the style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function expand(obj){
    obj.style.position="relative";
    obj.style.left="-100px";
    obj.style.top="-100px";
    obj.style.width="200px";
    obj.style.height="200px";
}
function smaller(obj){
    obj.style.position="static";
    obj.style.width="100px";
    obj.style.height="100px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="height:150px">
        <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here 
        Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:200px"></td>
    <td>
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px" id="needThisContainer">
            <img src="picture.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" 
                onmouseover="expand(this);" 
                onmouseout="smaller(this)"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>    
</tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work...  However when I put in jsfiddle, image is not showing up for some reason.  http://jsfiddle.net/Nk9w3/

Comment: The img (image) element src (source) property has to point to an actual image.